# Moving forward with f-Char and F-Char in VIm

Tags: vim

I understand that in Normal mode to move forward with vim I would do something like:

```
fo
```

to move to the next "o".

And even though `.` does not work to repeat that, it seems `;` does. But what about going back?
From the help menu it seems that `,` should do it but since I overwrote it with my leader key, now I'm wondering what people do for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `,` should work for you even if  you have `,` as `leader`.

after pressing `,` , wait for a while, see what happens

Comment: Correct thanks. I do the same with my jk mapping but I was wondering if there was a faster way for those impatient? Also is there any way to span multiple lines or is that just /searchpattern ?. Thanks

Comment: @JohnTomson, use `/foo` for searching forward across multiple lines and `?foo` for searching backward. Use `n` to jump to the next match and `N` for the previous match. The directions of `nN` are relative to the direction of the search so `n` after `/foo` goes forward but it goes "backward" after `?foo`. The same rules apply to `,;` after `tTfF`.

Comment: @JohnTomson "For those impatient," either map `,` to something else (e.g. `nnoremap \ ,`) or use `<CR>` after `,` to terminate the sequence immediately.

Comment: Thanks you for both of those answers